# VBA Excel Converting a KeyPress validation to a class module to be able to use it to multiple forms

Tags: vba, excel

I found a code online for validating user input to textbox to numeric only and restricting copy/paste. So what I wanted to do is convert it to a class module that I could use by calling it rather than putting the code to every textboxes. I already search online but they're using a different approach for validation. Appreciate it if someone could help. Here's the code.

```
'~~> Disable Pasting CTRL V , SHIFT + INSERT
Private Sub txtLvl_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If (Shift = 2 And KeyCode = vbKeyV) Or (Shift = 1 And KeyCode = vbKeyInsert) Then
    KeyCode = 0
End If
End Sub

'~~> Preventing input of non numerics
Private Sub txtLvl_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Select Case KeyAscii
  Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyLeft, _
  vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
  Case Else
    KeyAscii = 0
    Beep
End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every single text box that requires this restriction will need a Sub. You can easily put these restriction Subs in a separate Module say "RestrictionHelpers" and turn them into Functions, so for each textbox of those events, make the KeyCode/KeyAscii = their respective function name. You don't need to create a Class for this. Hope this is clear.

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/05/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: look at this. This is a possible solution. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=80631

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys. I needed to add another sub that prevents the user to use Shift + Insert to paste something and it works like a charm. Thanks all